# Is it possible to detect Core or system Temperature of iPhone?

Tags: iphone

is it available in iphone sdk ?
if yes could you show me some example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but there's no public API for it (you need `IOKit` to communicate with the hardwares).

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not available.

It maybe possible if you're using an external accessory or hardware.

Here's the API:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/EAAccessory_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Having worked with it, I can guarantee you that the External Accessory framework does *not* provide this information.